# Why won't dhcpd listen on the virtual interface

Tags: centos, dhcp, ifconfig, isc-dhcpd

I think I might be missing something simple, but I'm at the point of needing some extra eyes on the problem.  I have a need for 2 separate networks to be on the same NIC (**eth1**): **192.168.0.0/24** and **192.168.1.0/24**.  The interfaces are:

```
eth1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.1.250  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
    ether 0c:c4:7a:7d:bb:f8  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 24515  bytes 5405247 (5.1 MiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 31116  bytes 3036051 (2.8 MiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
    device interrupt 16  memory 0xdf200000-df220000  

eth1:1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.0.250  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
    ether 0c:c4:7a:7d:bb:f8  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    device interrupt 16  memory 0xdf200000-df220000
```

In `/etc/sysconfig/dhcpd` I have

```
DHCPD_INTERFACE="eth1 eth1:1"
DHCPDARGS="eth1 eth1:1"
```

In `/etc/dhcpd.conf` I have

```
subnet 192.168.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
    pool {
       ....
    }
}
subnet 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
    pool {
        ....
    }
}
```

Yet, when I start dhcpd, I see this

```
$ sudo journalctl -xeu dhcpd.service
  ....
dhcpd[5113]: No subnet declaration for eth1:1 (no IPv4 addresses).
dhcpd[5113]: ** Ignoring requests on eth1:1.  If this is not what
dhcpd[5113]:    you want, please write a subnet declaration
dhcpd[5113]:    in your dhcpd.conf file for the network segment
dhcpd[5113]:    to which interface eth1:1 is attached. **
  ....
```

Why?

Comment: Instead of using "virtual interfaces", have you tried simply assigning both addreses to `eth1`? That works perfectly fine on my system.

Comment: @grawity yes I did try that as well.  `ifconfig` did not show both addresses but I could ping them (curious).  I was using these: https://www.ostechnix.com/how-to-assign-multiple-ip-addresses-to-single-network-card-in-linux/.  However, I did run into similar issues with dhcpd though not the one listed above.  Specifically, dhcpd would not vend addresses on the *second* network assigned.

Comment: That's only because `ifconfig` has been written for obsolete APIs and has no understanding of multiple IP addresses per interface – even though Linux in general and modern tools (such as `ip addr`) have supported that for many years. Do not use ifconfig on Linux.

Comment: Also, are those `subnet` declarations inside a `shared-network` declaration for eth1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Network interface names like `eth1:1` do not designate separate interfaces, not even virtual ones. `eth1:1` is just an alias for the `eth1` interface that exists because `ifconfig` is dumb (and should not be used, as noted in the comments above.)

You should use a `shared-network` declaration for `eth1` including the two `subnet` declarations. An IP address for both subnets should also be assigned to `eth1`. Btw, you can add a label to the address to achieve compatibility with `ifconfig`, e.g.

```
 ip addr add 192.168.1.250/24 label eth1:1 dev eth1
```

There is still one problem: the clients' requests come in on a single wire, each request containing the client's MAC address and 0.0.0.0 as the source IP address. If a dynamic IP address is to be handed out, the DHCP server has no clue from which subnet it should assign an IP address to the client. The `shared-network` setting is intended for the case where two or more subnets are combined in a pool of addresses, and is really not suitable for subnets having different roles.

Comment: This answer is quite consistent with my findings.